# How can one connect Xtext to an existing compiler?

Tags: xtext

The Xtext `doGenerate` method takes an `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource` as the representation of the file to be compiled.  This is essentially an abstract syntax tree. In our application we already have a compiler that converts a `java.io.Reader` to its own AST structure and then does the rest of the compilation.

So the question is what is the best way to connect an Xtext editor to an existing compiler?

Our current thinking is that if we we could convert the `ecore` `Resource` to a `Reader`, then we could generate from there. But can this be done? Should it be done? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like a reasonable approach. You may want to cast the resource to an `XtextResource`, ask it for its `IParseResult` and use the root node to obtain the underlying text. Passing this by means of a `StringReader` to existing infrastructure should be fine.

Please note that the Xtext generator uses a custom abstraction above the Eclipse file system. If your compiler want to write into the workspace / into an Eclipse project, you may want to adapt to this API. Otherwise you will face issues with the Eclipse resource model.